# Laravel and angular Angular, routes difference

Tags: angularjs, authentication, laravel

I am using Laravel for backend and Authentication and Angular for front end. for backend services i use 'api/' to access laravel and return response.

Now the problem is I have '/' in angular and in laravel. If I call from Laravel it should redirect to '/login' and if i call from angular it should go to dashboard.

this is confusing and also how do i call 'logout' and redirect to login from angular.

angular app.js

```
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'templates/admin/admindash.html',
            controller:'AdminDashController'
        });
        .when('/admin',{
            templateUrl:'templates/admin/admindash.html',
            controller:'AdminDashController'
        });
```

laravel routes

```
/** before login **/
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@login');

/** after login **/
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth' ), function(){

    /** api requesets **/
    Route::group(array('prefix'=>'api'), function(){
        Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin'), function(){

            Route::POST('cust_serv/getstaffs', 'CustServController@getstaffs');
            Route::POST('cust_serv/addstaff', 'CustServController@addstaff');
            Route::POST('cust_serv/getserv', 'CustServController@getserv');
            Route::POST('cust_serv/addserv', 'CustServController@addserv');         
        });
    });

    /*** after login redirect to angular ***/
    Route::get('/admin', function()
    {
        return View::make('home');
    });
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return View::make('home');
    });

});
```

angular logout method

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    $http.get('/logout');
}
```

Laravel logout method

```
public function Logout(){
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::intended('login');
}
```

All i need is to use Laravel routes before login and angular routes after login.
How to set this up?

Comment: I cant understand what you want to do, so please explain in more simple way.

Comment: I want to authenticate with laravel. It redirects to view containing angular. from their I should logout. Also while making http request i should check for logged-in and access control.

Comment: I dont know whether its called hybrid authentication.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but remember that angular is a single page application, so laravel routing should not interfere with angular routes whatsoever, when you navigate an angular app's routes you are never actually changing page.